# Key issues reading from memcache pool on ubuntu / solaris

Tags: ubuntu, solaris, memcached

Our environment consists of 6 memcached servers running on Solaris 10 boxes and application code running on a mix of Solaris and Ubuntu servers. We are running into issues accessing data set on one operating system and accessed from the other. The only instance where the keys can be accessed from either OS is when we only connect to a single cache server and not the pool. As soon as you add 2 or more servers into the pool all keys are only available on the OS they were created on.

Cache pool is all memcached 1.2.6 and application servers are running memcache PHP library at 1.86. All the servers in our Solaris and Ubuntu environment are 64bit.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's probably cliche - but have you considered upgrading to the latest version (1.4.4)  to see if there was possibly a bug fix that resolves this issue for you?  I haven't read through all the notes.  I can tell you, however between 1.2.6 and 1.4.4 there have been a LOT of bug fixes - we just recently went to 1.4.4 on our production environment from 1.2.4 and saw a lot of speed improvements as well.

One thing I did just think of... in the client you have the ability to choose whether or not to hash the key or store it as plain text - do you have this set the same way on both OS?

If you pool together 2 Solaris or Ubuntu servers instead of mixing is the problem solved?  Trying to narrow it down to either a client or a pooling issue.

Lastly, is there a reason you're mixing the OS loads?  In our environments we find it's easier to standardize that way its easier to deploy a new machine when needed.